# Filtered out rows still appearing further down in chain

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using chaining to clean a dataframe and I want to change the type of a column named `horatmin` to `datetime` type.

The column has rows with a string value `Varias` which (obviously) throws an error when using `to_datetime`.

For that reason, I've filtered out the rows with the `Varias` values.
The fact that the rows with `Varias` are filtered out is confirmed when I run a `value_counts()`:

[image: No Varias values]

However, when I apply `to_datetime`, I get the following error message: `Unknown string format: Varias` as if the rows with the `Varias` values were still there.

This is my code:

```
(df[(df["nombre"]=="SANTANDER")&(df["horatmin"]!='Varias')]
 .drop(columns=[
     "Unnamed: 0","indicativo", "altitud", "dir", "presMax", "horaPresMax", "presMin", "horaPresMin"])
 .replace(",",".", regex=True)
 .dropna()
 .assign(
     fecha = pd.to_datetime(df["fecha"])
     ,horatmin = pd.to_datetime(df["horatmin"])
       )
)
```

My understanding is that, if the `.assign` of my code comes after I have filtered out the rows with the `Varias` values, the `.assign` should apply to a dataframe that does not have those values any longer.

Any idea why it's not working?

Here is how the dataframe looks like and it can be found [here](https://github.com/AdnStart/Spain_Temperatures/blob/master/spain_temperatures.csv).

[image: Dataframe preview]

`print(df.head().to_dict())` gives this:

```
{'fecha': {0: Timestamp('2016-12-01 00:00:00'), 1: Timestamp('2016-12-02 00:00:00'), 2: Timestamp('2016-12-03 00:00:00'), 3: Timestamp('2016-12-04 00:00:00'), 4: Timestamp('2016-12-05 00:00:00')}, 'nombre': {0: 'SANTANDER', 1: 'SANTANDER', 2: 'SANTANDER', 3: 'SANTANDER', 4: 'SANTANDER'}, 'provincia': {0: 'CANTABRIA', 1: 'CANTABRIA', 2: 'CANTABRIA', 3: 'CANTABRIA', 4: 'CANTABRIA'}, 'tmed': {0: '15.0', 1: '12.6', 2: '12.8', 3: '14.9', 4: '18.1'}, 'prec': {0: '0.0', 1: '0.0', 2: '0.0', 3: '0.0', 4: '0.0'}, 'tmin': {0: '12.2', 1: '9.5', 2: '9.0', 3: '11.0', 4: '15.0'}, 'horatmin': {0: '23:20', 1: '23:59', 2: '05:05', 3: '00:40', 4: '07:55'}, 'tmax': {0: '17.8', 1: '15.6', 2: '16.6', 3: '18.8', 4: '21.2'}, 'horatmax': {0: '12:55', 1: '12:30', 2: '14:05', 3: '12:20', 4: '13:15'}, 'velmedia': {0: '3.3', 1: '2.2', 2: '1.9', 3: '5.6', 4: '2.8'}, 'racha': {0: '10.6', 1: '5.3', 2: '7.8', 3: '12.5', 4: '10.0'}, 'horaracha': {0: '03:08', 1: '07:15', 2: '21:03', 3: '03:50', 4: '01:38'}, 'sol': {0: '8.3', 1: '8.5', 2: '7.9', 3: '2.4', 4: '4.8'}}
```

Comment: Could you show a sample of your dataframe in the question?

Comment: Just added a preview of the dataframe

Comment: Nice, that helps. will you please also add the result of `print(df.head().to_dict())` ?

Comment: too long to add to a comment, so just added it to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is within the `assign()` you are operating on the original df, not the filtered `(df[(df["nombre"]=="SANTANDER")&(df["horatmin"]!='Varias')])`

If you do this, you should get the result you are looking for

```
(df[(df["nombre"]=="SANTANDER")&(df["horatmin"]!='Varias')]
 .drop(columns=[
     "Unnamed: 0","indicativo", "altitud", "dir", "presMax", "horaPresMax", "presMin", "horaPresMin"])
 .replace(",",".", regex=True)
 .dropna()
 .assign(fecha = df[(df["nombre"]=="SANTANDER")&(df["horatmin"]!='Varias')]["fecha"].astype('datetime64[ns]'),
        horatmin = df[(df["nombre"]=="SANTANDER")&(df["horatmin"]!='Varias')]["horatmin"].astype('datetime64[ns]')))

          fecha     nombre  provincia  tmed  prec  tmin            horatmin  tmax horatmax velmedia racha horaracha  sol
0    2016-12-01  SANTANDER  CANTABRIA  15.0   0.0  12.2 2021-12-07 23:20:00  17.8    12:55      3.3  10.6     03:08  8.3
1    2016-12-02  SANTANDER  CANTABRIA  12.6   0.0   9.5 2021-12-07 23:59:00  15.6    12:30      2.2   5.3     07:15  8.5
2    2016-12-03  SANTANDER  CANTABRIA  12.8   0.0   9.0 2021-12-07 05:05:00  16.6    14:05      1.9   7.8     21:03  7.9
3    2016-12-04  SANTANDER  CANTABRIA  14.9   0.0  11.0 2021-12-07 00:40:00  18.8    12:20      5.6  12.5     03:50  2.4
4    2016-12-05  SANTANDER  CANTABRIA  18.1   0.0  15.0 2021-12-07 07:55:00  21.2    13:15      2.8  10.0     01:38  4.8
...         ...        ...        ...   ...   ...   ...                 ...   ...      ...      ...   ...       ...  ...
1792 2021-10-28  SANTANDER  CANTABRIA  17.4    Ip  13.2 2021-12-07 00:00:00  21.5    22:15      3.9  11.4     18:20  7.7
1793 2021-10-29  SANTANDER  CANTABRIA  16.8   5.5  14.5 2021-12-07 19:00:00  19.2    02:30      2.8  13.3     00:20  0.0
1794 2021-10-30  SANTANDER  CANTABRIA  17.0   0.1  14.5 2021-12-07 23:59:00  19.4    04:00      3.3  11.7     04:31  0.1
1795 2021-10-31  SANTANDER  CANTABRIA  17.9  10.1  13.0 2021-12-07 23:30:00  22.8    10:30      5.6  15.3     10:20  1.2
1796 2021-11-01  SANTANDER  CANTABRIA  14.4    Ip  12.0 2021-12-07 00:30:00  16.8   Varias      6.4  16.1     21:40  8.6

fecha        datetime64[ns]
nombre               object
provincia            object
tmed                 object
prec                 object
tmin                 object
horatmin     datetime64[ns]
tmax                 object
horatmax             object
velmedia             object
racha                object
horaracha            object
sol                  object
dtype: object
```

Making it more condensed using a mask

```
mask = df[(df["nombre"]=="SANTANDER")&(df["horatmin"]!='Varias')]
(mask
 .drop(columns=[
     "Unnamed: 0","indicativo", "altitud", "dir", "presMax", "horaPresMax", "presMin", "horaPresMin"])
 .replace(",",".", regex=True)
 .dropna()
 .assign(fecha = mask["fecha"].astype('datetime64[ns]'),
        horatmin = mask["horatmin"].astype('datetime64[ns]')))
```